# Starting application from WiX in a Setup kit?

Tags: installation, wix, setup-project, wix3.5

I have an application that I have in a WiX installer package.  This package is a prerequisite (along with a couple of others) installed using a VS2010 Setup kit.

If I run the WiX installer alone, my application starts just fine after install.  But when I run setup.exe, the application does not start.  In my WiX wxs file, I have this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="LaunchApplication"
        After="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget"
      Value="[#MyApp.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication"
          BinaryKey="WixCA"
          DllEntry="WixShellExec"
          Impersonate="yes" />
```

Since my WiX msi is wrapped in the setup kit, I dont have any UI, and this application should ALWAYS start.

Any thoughts on what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Check a verbose log to see if WixShellExec is logging errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [dotnetinstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/).

It is a free tool and the benefit of using dotnetinstaller is you can merge your msi with that and can generate an exe which can be executed an administrator unlike msi file.

In dotnetinstaller you can have pre-conditions defined and much more.